# Swift CocoaPods Deployment - Can't access any functions

Tags: swift, github, cocoapods

I'm new to CocoaPods and wanted to explore it by deploying an open source github project ( Banner notification for curious )

So I followed step by step the Cocoapods Guide as well as the Trunk guide for deployment. OK.

So my pod is called AWBanner (github : https://github.com/Aymenworks/AWBanner ) and I can add it in any project that use pods like that : `pod 'AWBanner'`. No problem.

My pod library contains only one file I want to provide, which is : `AWBanner.swift`

Both `pod lib lint` and `pod spec lint` **success**. ✅

This is my spec file

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint AWBanner.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "AWBanner"
  s.version          = "0.1.1"
  s.summary          = 'An easy, customizable and soft Swift banner notification for iOS applications.'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!  
  s.description      = <<-DESC
An easy, customizable and soft banner notification for iOS applications.
AWBanner library provides an easy to use class to show a banner view on the screen ( wherever you want, you can specify the Y origin ).
The banner moves from the Y origin ( default 0, but you can change it ) and stays there until the duration you choose elapse ( Personally I choose in general 2.5s ).
To dismiss the banner before the time elapse, the user can tap it.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = "https://github.com/Aymenworks/AWBanner"
  # s.screenshots     = "www.example.com/screenshots_1", "www.example.com/screenshots_2"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "Rebouh Aymen" => ".." }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/Aymenworks/AWBanner.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/AWBanner.swift'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'AWBanner' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  }

  s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
end
```

So the problem is that when importing the lib in my swift project , like that : 

`import AWBanner`

No errors are found, but I can't use any functions I made. It's like it's an empty module. I can't access any of  my functions, even after setting them public.

Someone can give me pointers if I have missed something ?

Comment: Tried to use your pod and it looks ok to me... What do you mean by "can't use any functions" ?

Comment: What do you means by OK ?
I mean that AWBanner have a static function called showWithDuration(...) and it cannot find it. Is it the same for u ?

Comment: I can call showWithDuration(...) method without any issues... Do you have use_frameworks! in your Podfile?

Comment: Hum yes I have. I just tested to change scheme ( I created before a Stub Scheme ) and going back to my main scheme and yeah it works.  So it's my new scheme that's not working.